# Grouping by fields after reduce is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

There is a complex object and based on an array which is given as an input I need to modify its properties. Illustration is shown below. If the "field" is same , add them to "or" array .If its different "field" add them to "and" array along with its "value". I am using Set to get keys from both source and input and using them to group based on its keys.  Also whenever there are duplicates .ie., suppose the "filterObj" already has the same (field, value) pair. Be it in "and" or inside "or",Then don't add it in the final object

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-so-dpvis

There is a TestCases file in the sandbox which its needs to pass

```
let filterObj = {
  feature: "test",
  filter: {
    and: [{ field: "field2" }]
  }
};
let obj = [{ field: "field2", value: "3" }];
let all_filters = [];
if (filterObj.filter.and && filterObj.filter.and.hasOwnProperty("or")) {
  all_filters = [...filterObj.filter.and.or];
} else if (filterObj.filter.and) {
  all_filters = [...filterObj.filter.and];
}
const all_objs = [...obj, ...all_filters];
const uniqKeys = all_objs.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => [...new Set([...acc, curr.field])],
  []
);
const updateItems = uniqKeys.map(obj => {
  const filter_items = all_objs.filter(item => item.field === obj);
  let resultObj = {};
  if (filter_items && filter_items.length > 1) {
    resultObj.or = [...filter_items];
  } else if (filter_items && filter_items.length === 1) {
    resultObj = { ...filter_items[0] };
  }
  return resultObj;
});
var result = { ...filterObj, filter: { and: [...updateItems] } };
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it.
I redid the implementation, it happened more universally.
Parses any filters according to your algorithm that it finds.
All test cases are worked.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-so-i1u6h

```
let filterObj = {
  feature: "test",
  filter: {
    and: [
      {
        field: "field1",
        value: "2"
      }
    ]
  }
};

let obj = [
  {
    field: "field1",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    field: "field1",
    value: "1"
  }
];

var FilterController = function(filter) {
  var self = this;
  self.filter = filter;
  // encapsulated map of objects by fields
  var storeMap = {};
  // counter of objects
  var counter = 0;

  var tryPutObjectToMap = function(object) {
    if (typeof object === "object") {
      // get type for grouping
      var objectType = self.getObjectGroupType(object);
      if (objectType !== null) {
        // cheack have group
        if (!storeMap.hasOwnProperty(objectType)) {
          storeMap[objectType] = [];
        }

        var duplicate = storeMap[objectType].find(function(sObject) {
          return self.getObjectValue(sObject) === self.getObjectValue(object);
        });

        // check duplicate
        if (duplicate === undefined) {
          counter++;
          storeMap[objectType].push(object);
        } else {
          // TODO: Handle duplicates
        }
      } else {
        // TODO: handle incorrect object
      }
    }
  };

  // get filter structure from map
  var getFilterStructureFromMap = function() {
    var result = {};

    // check exists root filter and filed if have objects
    if (counter > 0) {
      result["and"] = [];
    }

    for (var key in storeMap) {
      if (storeMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var array = storeMap[key];
        if (array.length > 1) {
          result["and"].push({
            // clone array
            or: array.slice()
          });
        } else {
          result["and"].push(array[0]);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  // rewrite and get current filter
  // if you need^ create new object for result
  self.rewriteAndGetFilter = function() {
    self.filter.filter = getFilterStructureFromMap();
    return self.filter;
  };

  // not prototype function for have access to storeMap
  self.putObjects = function(objects) {
    if (Array.isArray(objects)) {
      // recursive push array elements
      objects.forEach(element => self.putObjects(element));
      // handle array
    } else if (typeof objects === "object") {
      // handle object
      if (objects.hasOwnProperty("and") || objects.hasOwnProperty("or")) {
        for (var key in objects) {
          //no matter `or` or `and` the same grouping by field
          // inner object field
          if (objects.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            self.putObjects(objects[key]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // filters props not found, try push to store map
        tryPutObjectToMap(objects);
      }
    } else {
      // TODO: Handle errors
    }
  };

  if (self.filter.hasOwnProperty("filter")) {
    // put and parse current objects from filter
    self.putObjects(self.filter.filter);
  }
};

// function for grouping objects.
// for you get filed name from object.
// change if need other ways to compare objects.
FilterController.prototype.getObjectGroupType = function(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty("field")) {
    return obj.field;
  }
  return null;
};

// get object value
FilterController.prototype.getObjectValue = function(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "object" && obj.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
    return obj.value;
  }
  return null;
};

var ctrl = new FilterController(filterObj);
ctrl.putObjects(obj);
var totalFilter = ctrl.rewriteAndGetFilter();
console.log(totalFilter);
console.log(JSON.stringify(totalFilter));
```

**EDIT 1**

I did not change the logic; I made a function based on it.

```
let filterObj = {
  feature: "test",
  filter: {
    and: [
      {
        field: "field1",
        value: "2"
      }
    ]
  }
};

let obj = [
  {
    field: "field1",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    field: "field1",
    value: "1"
  }
];

function appendToFilter(filter, inputObjects) {
  var storeMap = {};
  var counter = 0;
  var handlingQueue = [];
  // if filter isset the appen to handling queue
  if (filter.hasOwnProperty("filter")) {
    handlingQueue.push(filter.filter);
  }
  // append other object to queue
  handlingQueue.push(inputObjects);
  // get first and remove from queue
  var currentObject = handlingQueue.shift();
  while (currentObject !== undefined) {
    if (Array.isArray(currentObject)) {
      currentObject.forEach(element => handlingQueue.push(element));
    } else if (typeof currentObject === "object") {
      if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty("and") || currentObject.hasOwnProperty("or")) {
        for (var key in currentObject) {
          if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            handlingQueue.push(currentObject[key]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // TODO: append fild exists check
        if (currentObject.field) {
          if (!storeMap.hasOwnProperty(currentObject.field)) {
            storeMap[currentObject.field] = [];
          }
          var localValue = currentObject.value;
          // check duplicate
          if (storeMap[currentObject.field].find(object => object.value === localValue) === undefined) {
            counter++;
            storeMap[currentObject.field].push(currentObject);
          } 
        } 
      }
    }

    currentObject = handlingQueue.shift();
  }

  // create new filter settings

  var newFilter = {};

  // check exists root filter and filed if have objects
  if (counter > 0) { newFilter["and"] = []; }

  for (var storeKey in storeMap) {
    if (storeMap.hasOwnProperty(storeKey)) {
      var array = storeMap[storeKey];
      if (array.length > 1) {
        newFilter["and"].push({
          // clone array
          or: array.slice()
        });
      } else {
        newFilter["and"].push(array[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  filter.filter = newFilter;
}

// update filterObj
appendToFilter(filterObj, obj);
console.log(filterObj);
```

**EDIT 2,3 (UPDATED)**

With others objects support.

```
export function appendToFilter(filter, inputObjects) {
  var storeMap = {};
  var others = [];
  var counter = 0;
  var handlingQueue = [];
  // if filter isset the appen to handling queue
  if (filter.hasOwnProperty("filter") && filter.filter.hasOwnProperty("and")) {
    handlingQueue.push(filter.filter.and);
  }
  // append other object to queue
  handlingQueue.push(inputObjects);
  // get first and remove from queue
  var currentObject = handlingQueue.shift();
  while (currentObject !== undefined) {
    if (Array.isArray(currentObject)) {
      currentObject.forEach(element => handlingQueue.push(element));
    } else if (typeof currentObject === "object") {
      if (
        currentObject.hasOwnProperty("and") ||
        currentObject.hasOwnProperty("or")
      ) {
        for (var key in currentObject) {
          if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            handlingQueue.push(currentObject[key]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        // TODO: append fild exists check
        if (currentObject.field) {
          if (!storeMap.hasOwnProperty(currentObject.field)) {
            storeMap[currentObject.field] = [];
          }
          var localValue = currentObject.value;
          // check duplicate
          if (
            storeMap[currentObject.field].find(
              object => object.value === localValue
            ) === undefined
          ) {
            counter++;
            storeMap[currentObject.field].push(currentObject);
          }
        } else {
          // handle others objects^ without field "field"
          counter++;
          others.push(currentObject);
        }
      }
    }
    currentObject = handlingQueue.shift();
  }
  // create new filter settings
  var newFilter = {};
  // check exists root filter and filed if have objects
  if (counter > 0) {
    newFilter["and"] = [];
  }
  for (var storeKey in storeMap) {
    if (storeMap.hasOwnProperty(storeKey)) {
      var array = storeMap[storeKey];
      if (array.length > 1) {
        newFilter["and"].push({
          // clone array
          or: array.slice()
        });
      } else {
        newFilter["and"].push(array[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  // Append others to result filter
  others.forEach(other => newFilter["and"].push(other));
  filter.filter = newFilter;
}
```

Comment: Wait a few minutes.

Comment: I created function based on previous sample.

Comment: @ Aleksandr Smityukh Sorry to say test cases 3 and 4 are failing with your latest code. check this https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-so-gksmc

Comment: in fact, 3 and 4 contradict 7 and 8. In 3 and 4, duplicates remain. Moreover, for 7 and 8 they are deleted. There are two options. Or incorrect test cases. Or not completely described the logic of removing duplicates. But I am inclined to the first option. Describe how duplicates should be handled and I will fix it. Now duplicates are objects in which the fields "field" and "value" are identical.

Comment: Was there a problem in the tests?

Comment: See new version of function.

Comment: Its work! https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-withtc-1zk38 tests not pass because of sort! Your test cases do not take append order)

Comment: It's my pleasure!